# MariaDB Galera Cluster: change wresp_sst_method in production server

Tags: mariadb, rsync, galera

I have a MariaDB Galera Cluster with 3 nodes and multi-master setup.
my current configuration for State Snapshot Transfer method is `rsync`.

How to change this method to `xtrabackup-v2` without downtime and data loss?
Can I shutdown and setup nodes one by one?

Comment: When in doubt, do such a rolling shutdown+restart.

Comment: I mean in a cluster, can I have different sst methods on different nodes?